# php command not found but php70 is working

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, centos

This is the server configuration. I need to isntalll `php v7.0.33`

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

First I did `yum install php` but it installed `php v7.3`.

So, I removed it, and installed `yum install php70`

Now if I do `php -v` I get `php command not found`
But If I do `php70 -v` I get version.

Comment: Have you tried `yum install php-cli`?

Comment: What version of PHP do you want?

Comment: You are confused by base vs SCL packages, read the FAQ;
https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Answer (score 0):

I, now, setup everything successfully.
I followed below steps.

```
yum remove php70 && yum autoremove
yum -y install epel-release.noarch yum-utils
yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum info php // it will show the version that will be install in the next setp
yum -y install php
```

Comment: For a proper PHP installation using my repository, simply follow the Wizard: 
https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/